# MTM wrong video attachment in test result

Tags: tfs, automation, mtm

We have an automated test run (TFS 2013, MTM 2013) and in the Test Settings we have configured 'Screen and Voice Recorder' to be on.
The problem is that the wrong video is displayed when opening an attachment after a test run.

For example, the latest run is from 29/8, and when opening a video attachment, the video that is opened is from 25/8.

Have anyone encountered this issue?

A few more points that might help -
For this run, we have a test controller and two test agents, Let`s call them 1 and 2. The test controller is installed on machine 1, and the problem only exists when opening an attachment from agent 1. When opening an attachment from agent 2 - everything is ok.
Both machines are Windows Server 2012 R2 (Datacenter).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Adding more info: attachments from all tests on agent 1 open the exact same video.

Answer (score 1):

What about user's who is running services? Are they domain, local accounts? Test controller stores test result data in user profile directory. Maybe test controller and agent are running on the same user?

MTM > LAB > Controllers has RMB menu to clean up local store. Try this and run test again. Controllers stores few test runs of test results as backup

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)
Test controller and agent are running on the same user, but i don`t think it should be a problem...

Comment: In addition, I have noticed that the video displayed is the first one right after a system restart...

Comment: Please check the system time zone in all machines, and then re-run it again.